# Programmatically select ComponentOne TrueDBGrid Filterbar

Tags: .net, componentone, truedbgrid

I'm using a ComponentOne TrueDBGrid control, with the filterbar enabled. I'd like to modify the the default behaviour so that when a cell in the filterbar is clicked, the text in that cell is automatically selected. Normally I'd wireup a MouseDown event and use the CellContaining method to check which cell has been clicked, but this only ever returns -1 for both row and col for the filterbar. So I can't identify an individual cell, and I don't know how to select a particular cell in the filterbar.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting solution in case anyone else runs into this problem.

You need to capture kind of grid element beneath the coordinate you clicked on, using PointAtEnum. Then you may simply set the cell in EditMode by setting the grid’s EditActive property to True. And this is how you do it at MouseUp event:

```
Private Sub C1TrueDBGrid1_MouseUp(sender As Object, _
               e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
                  Handles C1TrueDBGrid1.MouseUp

If Me.C1TrueDBGrid1.PointAt(e.X, e.Y) = _
    C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.PointAtEnum.AtFilterBar Then
    Me.C1TrueDBGrid1.EditActive = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and fixed a major annoyance with this grid control - thanks!